# Why git cannot merge a text file with different changes in different lines?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I was wondering if some of you have faced this issue.

I have a txt file in my main branch. I added 4 lines

```
Line1
Line2
Line3 
Line4
```

Then I created 2 branches from the main. feature1 and feature2.

In feature1 I changed the first line from *Line1* to *Line1changed*.
In feature2 I changed the second line from *Line2* to    *Line2changed*.

I merged feature1 into main branch without any problem, then when I tried to merge feature2 into main branch a conflict was detected.

```
$ git merge feature2
Auto-merging file.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I would like to know why.

```
$ git diff
diff --cc file.txt
index cd3d4bb,bb25698..0000000
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@@ -1,4 -1,4 +1,9 @@@
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +Line1changed
 +Line2
++=======
+ Line1
+ Line2changed
++>>>>>>> feature2
  Line3
  Line4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default merge configuration will auto-merge if changes don't overlap.  But "overlap" is defined in a way that includes adjacent lines.  So for example, when you make a change to line 1, that would overlap another change on line 1 *or* line 2 (as well as insertions before or after line 1).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Git's merge algorithm, but I seem to recall that there is a proximity threshold for changes to adjacent lines, which triggers a conflict to happen.  To recap, first you added four new lines in the `main` branch:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3 
Line4
```

Then, you branched into `feature1` and `feature2`, editing the first line in `feature1`:

```
Line1changed
Line2
Line3 
Line4
```

When you merged this back into the `main` branch, there was no conflict, because only the first line was changed.  However, when you merged `feature2` into `main`, both the first and second lines had different versions, i.e.

```
Line1changed (feature1)   Line1        (feature1)
Line2        (feature1)   Line2changed (feature2)
```

This triggered a merge conflict, because these two lines are directly adjacent to each other.  I think it would have also happened for similar changes within some number of lines apart.

But the bottom line is that merge conflicts are a fact of life in software development, in Git, and really any other VCS tool.